How to mock psycopg2.connect when used with closing of contextlib module?
I have following class Database with get_data method. It uses 'closing' of 'contextlib' module to close the connection.
class Database:

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.db_details = {<connection details>}

    def get_data(self, query, parameters):

        with closing(psycopg2.connect(**self.db_details)) as conn:
            with conn.cursor() as cursor:
                cursor.execute(query, parameters)
                data = cursor.fetchall()

        return data

By referring this solution, I've came up with the following unit test
class TestDatabase(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch("psycopg2.connect")
    @patch("Database.__init__")
    def test_get_data_pos(self, mock_init, mock_connect):

        expected_result = [(1, "John", "New York City")]
        query = "SELECT * FROM user_details;"
        parameters = {}

        mock_init.return_value = None

        db_inst = Database()
        db_inst.db_details = {
            <some_dummy_values>
        }

        mock_con_cm = mock_connect.return_value
        mock_conn = mock_con_cm.__enter__.return_value
        mock_cur = mock_conn.cursor.return_value.__enter__.return_value
        mock_cur.fetchall.return_value = expected_result

        actual_result = db_inst.get_data(query, parameters)

        self.assertEqual(expected_result, actual_result)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()


But I'm getting following assertion error:
AssertionError: [(1, 'John', 'New York City')] != <MagicMock name='connect().cursor().__ent[35 chars]384'>

Note: I can not modify the implementation of Database class.

get_data should probably just take an open connection (or even a cursor) as an argument. Let the caller worry about whether that connection needs to (or can be) closed.

Ah! After scratching head for some hours, I was able to make the unittest pass but had to patch the "closing" method of the "contextlib" module.
class TestDatabase(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch("database.closing")
    @patch("psycopg2.connect")
    @patch("Database.__init__")
    def test_get_data_pos(self, mock_init, mock_connect, mock_closing):

        expected_result = [(1, "John", "New York City")]
        query = "SELECT * FROM user_details;"
        parameters = {}

        mock_init.return_value = None

        db_inst = Database()
        db_inst.db_details = {<dummy_details>}

        mock_connect.return_value = None

        # This is the object assigned to conn in: 
        # "with closing(psycopg2.connect(**self.db_details)) as conn"
        mock_conn = MagicMock()
    
        # This is the object assigned to cursor in:  
        # "with conn.cursor() as cursor"
        mock_cursor = MagicMock()

        mock_cursor.fetchall.return_value = expected_result
    
        # Objects to return when context managers are invoked
        mock_conn.cursor.return_value.__enter__.return_value = mock_cursor
        mock_closing.return_value.__enter__.return_value = mock_conn

        actual_result = db_inst.get_data(query, parameters)

        self.assertEqual(expected_result, actual_result)


from unittest import mock

import psycopg2

db_inst = Database()
db_inst.db_details = {<some_dummy_values>}

expected_result = [(1, "John", "New York City")]
query = "SELECT * FROM user_details;"
parameters = {}

with mock.patch(target="your_module.psycopg2.connect", return_value=mock.Mock(
    spec=psycopg2.connect, **{"return_value.cursor.return_value.fetchall": expected_result
                              })):
    actual_result = db_inst.get_data(query, parameters)

self.assertEqual(expected_result, actual_result)

As a decorator
@mock.patch(target="your_module.psycopg2.connect", return_value=mock.Mock(
    spec=psycopg2.connect, **{"return_value.cursor.return_value.fetchall": expected_result
                              }))

